# Crosscompiling with distcc on Raspberry Pi Cluster

Tags: pi-3, cluster

I wanted to make a cluster of Raspberry Pi's for distributed compiling (C++), so I started with just one Pi for testing.

After installing `distcc` on my PC and the Pi and configuring them the compiler says:

```
distcc[3784] (dcc_build_somewhere) Warning: failed to distribute,
running locally instead
```

`/etc/default/distcc` on my machine:

```
STARTDISTCC="true" #
ALLOWEDNETS="10.10.10.0/24" 
LISTENER="10.10.10.201" 
NICE="10" 
JOBS="" 
ZEROCONF="false"
```

`/etc/distcc/hosts` on my machine:

```
10.10.10.60
```

`/etc/default/distcc` on the Pi:

```
STARTDISTCC="true" 
ALLOWEDNETS="10.10.10.0/24" 
LISTENER="127.0.0.1" 
NICE="10" 
JOBS="" 
ZEROCONF="false"
```

/etc/distcc/hosts on the Pi:

```
+zeroconf
```

`Distcc` already worked when we used the PCs in our office but it doesn't work when we try to use the Pi's.

Also, yesterday I took a look into the `distcc` log on the Pi and it said something with `COMPILE_ERROR` but after reinstalling the Pi the log stays empty.

The programm has to run on a x86 processor later.